# Gradle: Could not resolve me.champeau.gradle:gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin:0.1

Tags: groovy, migration, jcenter

I'm trying to upgrade Gradle version from 4.10.3 to 6.8 for project https://archive.apache.org/dist/groovy/2.5.8/sources/apache-groovy-src-2.5.8.zip
and for that I modified build.gradle this way https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/c2fe31c429d19ecf2e08e53f638de451 , but I have the following error building this project:

```
└─$ ./gradlew -PskipIndy clean distBin                                                                                                                   1 ⨯
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'groovy'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve me.champeau.gradle:gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin:0.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve me.champeau.gradle:gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin:0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/melix/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin/me/champeau/gradle/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin/0.1/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin-0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/melix/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin/me/champeau/gradle/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin/0.1/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin-0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Could you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Bintray was closed. Find another repo with required artifact. https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/02/jfrog-jcenter-bintray-closure/

Comment: @daggett Sorry I do not understand: mavenCentral() is on and this plugin is available there https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.champeau.gradle/gradle-javadoc-hotfix-plugin/0.1 but gradle looks in bintray, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin found in the repository

```
maven `{ url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
```

look here [https://gitee.com/mirrors/spring-social/blob/master/build.gradle`](https://gitee.com/mirrors/spring-social/blob/master/build.gradle%60)